"depend on contexts" or "depend on context" or "depend on the context"?
When I want to say an expression (or expressions) means different things in different situations, should I say which of the following (I assume a context won't work)?

The meaning depends on (contexts, context, the context).

For other examples:

"I'm sorry" has different implications, depending on (contexts, context, the context)
It depends on (contexts, context, the context) which of Expression A and Expression B is more appropriate.

There may be, again, contextual factors that affects whether the context is appropriate, but mainly I'm thinking when I answer questions asked in the generic setting (like Does expression X mean such and such?).

Plural contexts isn't idiomatic here. Whether or not to include the article is a stylistic choice that has no effect on meaning, but I'd say "It would depend on the context" if I was being relatively formal, otherwise just "It depends on context" for short and to the point.

"context" or "the context" would be equally acceptable. The word is treated as uncountable.
In this case I don't really see any difference from adding the article. Omitting it is a stylistic choice. It makes the sentence a little more terse.

Does that extend to other nouns: preference, taste, style ... (to me, similar in countability) and factor, situation,... (that look "more countable" to me)?

Yes,  I'd say those would be treated as non-count in that context.
